# Is there a way to spy/mock using Jest on fat arrow class instance methods for React components?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a `handleClick` function:

```
handleClick = tagIndex => {
    console.log(tagIndex)
    if (tagIndex >= 0 && tagIndex < this.state.suggestedTags.length)
        this.state.suggestedTags.splice(tagIndex, 1);
}
```

inside of my React class and I'm not able to mock or spy on it properly.

I'm currently trying this

```
it('should call handleClick when a tag is clicked', () => {
        wrapper.setState({ suggestedTags: ['Mozart'] })
        const spy = jest.spyOn(component, 'handleClick')
        component.forceUpdate()
        wrapper.find('.suggested-tags__item').simulate('click')
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
```

but all I get back is `Expected mock function to have been called`

Comment: Can you try `jest.spyOn(Component.prototype, 'handleClick')` Note here -
 Component here is class name of Component and not just `component` instance.

Comment: You can't. `handleClick` will be an instance method and won't get attached to `prototype`. Either test the consequence of the `handleClick` without mocking it or use `bind` in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(component, 'handleClick')
wrapper.instance().forceUpdate(); // Here is the difference
wrapper.find('.suggested-tags__item').simulate('click')
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/365

Comment: Note that `component` here being passed to spyOn should be the wrapper.instance()